# Using a property of T to create a new object of the property type with the property values?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, reflection, activator

I need a way to convert the properties of an object of type T to objects of the property type, and values as they are in T. My reason for doing this is so that I can check if the property is or inherits from IEnumerable (Lists, arrays, etc.), **and if it does then I need to pass that IEnumerable as an object to be worked on.** So far I have

```
foreach (var propInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(propInfo.PropertyType, propInfo.GetValue(obj));
            if (ObjectProcessing.ImplementsIEnumerable(newObject))
            {
                ObjectProcessing.ObjectQueue.Enqueue(newObject);
            }
        }
```

Which unfortunately doesn't work. I cant use `CreatInstance<T>` because it seems the compiler assumes T is the T in the method signature, which is the source object not the target object.

Comment: Please provide a clear explanation of what you want to achieve, a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in code, a description of expected behaviour vs. what you observe

Comment: This looks like a X-Y question. Why do you need to create an instance of the property to see if it inherits IEnumerable?

Comment: Edited for clarity. I already have the method that checks, but if it returns true I need to pass the parameter as an object independent of its parent class.

Comment: @HenryPuspurs, Keep in mind that If you create a `new` instance using `Activator.CreateInstance` it will not be the same as original objects instance

Comment: I dont need it to be, I need it to be a new object of the type of the property, with the value of the property, independent of the original object.

Comment: @HenryPuspurs, Let me get it straight. You want to use no generic ersion of `Activator.CreateInstance` and you need the return type not of `object`? A little bit more of code would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question looks like a XY problem. What is [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

You do not need to create an instance of the object to see if it implements or is `IEnumerable`. Let me build upon what you have so far

```
// This is the example object
public class MyClass {
    public IEnumerable A{ get;set;}
    public List<int> B{get;set;}
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
foreach (var propInfo in myClass.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    var typeOfProperty = propInfo.PropertyType;
    var isIEnuerableOrInheritingFromIt = typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeOfProperty);
    if (isIEnuerableOrInheritingFromIt) {
        var objectThatImplementsIEnumerable = propInfo.GetValue(myClass);
        // Do stuff with it
    }
}
```

Comment: As in the above comments. I can already check and return true or false, but on true I need to pass that parameter as an object.

Comment: @HenryPuspurs, you can already see in the answer how to get the object. Ask further if there some other not clear parts

Comment: ok I'll mark this correct. For those reading the correction that works is 'var newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(propInfo.PropertyType, propInfo.GetValue(obj));' needs to be 'var newObject = propInfo.GetValue(obj);'